# Can't we set the old windows password again?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login

Consider this scenario:

I'm using windows 7. Initially I had the login password as "first". After sometime I changed it to "second". If I try to set the password as "first" again, windows not accepting and says the password isn't met the requirements.

So, Can't we set the previous windows password again? and if possible, what's the way?

Comment: This is set within group policy as you are part of a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a policy set by you, or more likely, your systems administrator.

You can check what it is by going to **Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy**

[image]

The option you need is "Enforce password history". This will be set to an none zero value so that you don't just alternate between a small number of passwords. If you are part of a domain where these are controlled centrally by group policy then these options will be disabled (greyed out).

One place I worked had a policy that the passwords had to be changed every 30 days and the history was set to 12.

The danger with this approach is that users simply choose passwords of the form:

> [passwordroot][number] (e.g. Password1)

and then just increment the number each month.

Comment: I checked the details. But I couldn't change the default values like Maximum password age or minimum password age, even if I'm the administrator. Note: I tried this in my office computer where all the computers are in the Network administrator's control.

Comment: @arulappan - that's to be expected if you are part of a domain.

Comment: :What do you mean by domain. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @arulappan - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain